# SQL - Greater than date query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the SQL query below and I would like to get only the records where the column "Last Update Date" is greater than or equal to 01/01/2016. Basically only records in 2016. When I use the query below, I don't get any errors but I am still getting every date returned not just 2016. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
SELECT
  NPI,
  [Entity Type Code],
  [Replacement NPI],
  [Employer Identification Number (EIN)],
  [Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)],
  [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)],
  [Provider First Name],
  [Provider Middle Name],
  [Provider Name Prefix Text],
  [Provider Name Suffix Text],
  [Provider Credential Text],
  [Provider Other Organization Name],
  [Provider Other Organization Name Type Code],
  [Provider Other Last Name],
  [Provider Other First Name],
  [Provider Other Middle Name],
  [Provider Other Name Prefix Text],
  [Provider Other Name Suffix Text],
  [Provider Other Credential Text],
  [Provider Other Last Name Type Code],
  [Provider First Line Business Mailing Address],
  [Provider Second Line Business Mailing Address],
  [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name],
  [Provider Business Mailing Address State Name],
  [Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code],
  [Provider Business Mailing Address Country Code (If outside U S )],
  [Provider Business Mailing Address Telephone Number],
  [Provider Business Mailing Address Fax Number],
  [Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address],
  [Provider Second Line Business Practice Location Address],
  [Provider Business Practice Location Address City Name],
  [Provider Business Practice Location Address State Name],
  [Provider Business Practice Location Address Postal Code],
  [Provider Business Practice Location Address Country Code (If outside U S )],
  [Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number],
  [Provider Business Practice Location Address Fax Number],
  [Provider Enumeration Date],
  [Last Update Date]
FROM Data
WHERE ([Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] IN ('122300000X', '1223G0001X'))
AND ([Last Update Date] >= '01/01/2016')
```

Comment: What data type is your `Last Update Date` column?

Comment: it is a varchar(200)

Comment: That's your problem, you probably need to cast them so they both hold the information in the same form. You could try casting them to DATE

Comment: nothing wrong with your syntax. just your schema. why u no make a date of date type???

Comment: You will find your queries work faster and can be written more intuitively if you store your dates in the appropriate date types.

Comment: Is you date format and schema is correct ?

Comment: as @aquiros said, casting to date is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead of  `([Last Update Date] >= '01/01/2016')` the following:

`YEAR( [Last Update Date]) = 2016`

to get all the records that updated in 2016

Comment: He wants greater than 2016-01-01, so you query won't work in the following years.

Comment: This won't scale well, if he needs more specifics dates between months for example.

Comment: He himself has replied that it worked, see comment above

Comment: This also seems to imply that the `Last Update Date` column _is_ some sort of date type.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, [Last Update Date], 101) >= '2016-01-01'
```

Note that the format mask you want is `101`, which corresponds to data in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).  This assumes that you are storing your dates in this format, telling by the format you used in your original `WHERE` clause while comparing.

Also note that you don't need to use `CONVERT` on the RHS of the comparsion in the above expression, because SQL Server should be able to deal with a date literal assuming it is in a standard format.

Answer (score 1):

Use Datetime in condition :

```
and CONVERT(datetime, [Last Update Date], 121) >= CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/2016',121)
```